# Changing check attribute of jquery dom items in a variable array

Tags: jquery, list, dom, checkbox, checked

Ok, So I have a list of checkboxes in a pop up. I grab two lists of jquery dom elements, a list of the checkboxes and a list of the checkboxes that are checked. The idea is that the user can change the checkboxes then if they want to, press a cancel button and it will revert to the original.

I get the two lists...

```
var allDropDownCheckboxes = $(this).next().find(".dropDownCheckbox");
var selectedCheckboxes = $(this).next().find(".dropDownCheckbox:checked");
```

On the cancel button being pressed I revert the checkboxes to their original state...

```
allDropDownCheckboxes.attr('checked', false);
selectedCheckboxes.attr('checked', true);
```

It unchecks them all but doesn't check the ones that were originally checked again...

Why?!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use **[.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)** instead of `.attr()` to set the `checked` state of form elements, from the **[docs](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)**:

> As of jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method returns undefined for attributes
>   that have not been set. To retrieve and change DOM properties such as
>   the checked, selected, or disabled state of form elements, use the
>   .prop() method.

```
allDropDownCheckboxes.prop('checked', false);
selectedCheckboxes.prop('checked', true);
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use .prop() instead of .attr()

```
allDropDownCheckboxes.prop('checked', false);
selectedCheckboxes.prop('checked', true);
```